# Highcharts - CUSTOM DATA LABELS in line series, are disappearing on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I have a line series, on which i display **custom data labels** for only particular value in the series. On Window resize, the data labels are disappearing from the chart. Is there any solution for this issue.
Thanks in Advance.

My code:

```
var options = {
            chart : {
                renderTo : 'container',
                type : 'line',
            },

        xAxis : {
            spacingTop: 50,
            spacingBottom: 25,
            categories : []
        },

        yAxis : [ {
            min: 0,
            minRange: 0.1
        } ],
        plotOptions: {
            line:{
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled:true,
                    defer:false,
                    formatter: function() {
                        count++;
                        if(this.y)
                            if(batch_info[count]!=0)
                                return batch_info[count];
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series : []
    };
```

`

Before window Resize:

[image]

After Maximizing Window:

[image]

Comment: Can you inspect element those labels and check what happening to their behaviour ? Also it would be good if you create any Fiddle/Codepen of the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A formatter callback is invoked on every redrawing/resizing, so the most likely scenario is that you do not reset `count` variable and as the result it accesses the non-existing value, e.g. `batch_info[101]` when the `batch_info.length === 100`.

You can use the modulo operator to avoid it:

```
formatter: function () {
                    count++;
                  return batch_info[count % batch_info.length];
                }
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/ck8zhLmj/1/

but I suggest refactoring the code and dropping the usage of `count` variable. Instead you can include the information about data label in the series' data or point object.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. During window resize, the `labels in x-Axis` is also disappearing(As shown in the above image). Can you please suggest a way to solve that too. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: They are hidden because there is not enough space. You can try to play with the axis labels setting, like staggerLines and rotation. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels
http://jsfiddle.net/L7psz0b3/

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to just reload the highcharts function after a resize.

```
 $(window).resize(function(){
     drawVisualization();
 });
```

Comment: drawVisualization(), keeps the labels even after resize, but doesn't maximize the chart according to the window size. The chart size remains the same as the previous window size.Can you please help.